# Comparing two .jar files

Tags: java, jar, comparison, diff

How do I compare two .jar files? 
Both of them have compiled .class files.

I want the difference in terms of method changes, etc.

Answer (score 114):

- [JAPICC](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker), sample usage:

  `japi-compliance-checker OLD.jar NEW.jar`

  Sample reports for log4j: http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/log4j/

  [image]
- [PkgDiff](http://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/), sample usage:

  `pkgdiff OLD.jar NEW.jar`

  See [sample report](https://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/package_diff/args4j/2.0.16/2.0.23/report.html) for args4j.

  [image]
- [Clirr](http://clirr.sourceforge.net/), sample usage:

  `java -jar clirr-core-0.6-uber.jar -o OLD.jar -n NEW.jar`

Comment: Andrey, what is the difference between those tools? Do they stem from the same core?

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov, no, these tools have different core. pkgdiff - visual comparison of classes declarations, japi-compliance-checker and clirr - analysis of changes (the first one is written in perl, the second - in java).

Comment: Have you tried integrating something with TeamCity? It seems clirr has a Maven Plugin and there is also a tool called JAPI-Checker.

Comment: Please note both Japi-Compliance-Checker and Pkgdiff do not compare everything. For example, all method implementations are ignored. Only method signatures, method removals and API compatibilities are generated as a report. If you are up to comparing binaries then you can opt to use tools like diff or cmp or IntelliJ plugin or even Beyond Compare!

Answer (score 49):

If you select two files in **IntellijIdea** and press `Ctrl + D`then it will show you the diff. I use *Ultimate* and don't know if it will work with *Community* edition.

Comment: @ChristianNilsson, works in 2018.2 on Mac 10.14 Mojave though

Comment: I made the mistake of selecting the Maven wrapper. Under _External Libraries_ one need to expand the wrapper and then select the jar-file. Thanks @xuesheng

Comment: Super easy solution.

Comment: Amazing that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Maybe they dumbed it down in the meantime. It complains that jar files are "unsupported binary files". I can list them with jar.exe, so clearly IntellijIdea isn't so intelligent these days. It also takes ages for it just list a directory in the file open dialog. An amazing piece of software. The dark grey on dark grey default theme is the usability cherry on the cake.

Comment: After fighting the obnoxious and barely legible interface for like 10 minutes, after putting in "full IDE" as opposed to "light mode", I managed to make it open a directory. And yeah, Ctrl+D kinda works as advertised after that. Except for "// Implementation of methods is not available". No idea  why not.

Comment: And yeah I have their two plugins mentioned [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/decompiler.html) enabled; they are so by default, but they don't work, at least not in diff mode.

Comment: It worked for me on version 2023.2.2 (Community Edition)

Answer (score 20):

1. Rename .jar to .zip
2. Extract
3. Decompile class files with [jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad)
4. Recursive [diff](http://ss64.com/bash/diff.html)

Comment: It's brute force, but that's exactly the way I'd do it. (Except that I might use `jar` to extract the contents, instead of renaming the file and using `pkunzip`.)

Comment: Optionally replace step 3 with a call to `javap -c` to keep it to bytecode (especially if by "method changes" the OP meant changes to a method's signature).

Comment: How would you deal with method bodies being moved up or down the source file? I think that would throw the `diff`ing of `javap` or `jad` output out of whack.

Answer (score 9):

Extract each jar to it's own directory using the jar command with parameters xvf. i.e. `jar xvf myjar.jar` for each jar.

Then, use the UNIX command `diff` to compare the two directories. This will show the differences in the directories. You can use `diff -r dir1 dir2` two recurse and show the differences in text files in each directory(.xml, .properties, etc).

This will also show if binary class files differ. To actually compare the class files you will have to decompile them as noted by others.

Answer (score 6):

**Create **a folder**** and create **another 2 folders** inside it like old and new. add relevant jar files to the folders. then open the first folder using IntelliJ. after that click whatever 2 files do you want to compare and **right-click** and click **compare archives**.

Answer (score 4):

I use to [ZipDiff](http://zipdiff.sourceforge.net/) lib (have both Java and ant API).

Comment: A useless app these days "    [changed] cbk.class  ( size 4895 : 4895 )" and like that for every single file.

Comment: This does not show the diff only shows filenames that are changed

Answer (score 3):

Here is my script to do the process described by sje397:

```
    #!/bin/sh

    # Needed if running on Windows
    FIND="/usr/bin/find"
    DIFF="diff -r"

    # Extract the jar (war or ear)
    JAR_FILE1=$1
    JAR_FILE2=$2

    JAR_DIR=${PWD}          # to assign to a variable
    TEMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)

    echo "Extracting jars in $TEMP_DIR"

    EXT_DIR1="${TEMP_DIR}/${JAR_FILE1%.*}"
    EXT_DIR2="${TEMP_DIR}/${JAR_FILE2%.*}"

    mkdir ${EXT_DIR1}
    cd ${EXT_DIR1}
    jar xf ${JAR_DIR}/${JAR_FILE1}
    jad -d . -o -t2 -safe -space -b -ff -s java -r **/*.class
    cd ..

    mkdir ${EXT_DIR2}
    cd ${EXT_DIR2}
    jar xf ${JAR_DIR}/${JAR_FILE2}
    jad -d . -o -t2 -safe -space -b -ff -s java -r **/*.class
    cd ..

    # remove class files so the diff is clean
    ${FIND} ${TEMP_DIR} -name '*.class' | xargs rm

    # diff recursively 
    ${DIFF} ${EXT_DIR1} ${EXT_DIR2}
```

I can run it on Windows using GIT for Windows. Just open a command prompt. Run bash and then execute the script from there.

Comment: Seems that you missed the last line:
`diff -r ${EXT_DIR1} ${EXT_DIR2}` or `${DIFF} ${EXT_DIR1} ${EXT_DIR2}` (if reuse your declared variable).
For those who are on cygwin, the script almost worked for me except two things that I've changed: 
1) I had to use built-in javap instead of jad, because I can't download jad (enterp. firewall ...);
2) as `jar xf` does't understand paths like `/cygwin/c/rest/of/path` which is returned by `pwd` in cygwin, I had to convert it to `c:/rest/of/path`:
`JAR_DIR=${PWD}`, `JAR_DIR=${JAR_DIR#*/cygdrive/c}`, `JAR_DIR="c:$JAR_DIR"`

Comment: You are correct @dpg. The last line was    ${DIFF} ${EXT_DIR1} ${EXT_DIR2}

Comment: What is `jad`? Don't have that binary available in PATH

Comment: Jad is a Java Decompiler. I think it is not maintained any longer but I found it available at http://www.javadecompilers.com/jad

Comment: In case your arguments (jar files) are in a subdirectory (like `foo/bar/toto.jar`), you need to add the `-p` argument to mkdir command

Answer (score 2):

Use [Java Decompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) to turn the jar file into source code file, and then use [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) to perform comparison.

You should consult the copyright holder of the source code, to see whether it is OK to do so.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux/CygWin a handy script I use at times is:

```
#Extract the jar (war or ear)
cd dir1
jar xvf jar-file1
for i in `ls *.class`
do
 javap $i > ${i}.txt #list the functions/variables etc
done

cd dir2
jar xvf jar-file2
for i in `ls *.class`
do
 javap $i > ${i}.txt #list the functions/variables etc
done

diff -r dir1 dir2 #diff recursively
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio**, add your jar files to a project under the libs folder.
Then select the both jar files, right click then select "**Compare Archives**"

Comment: Now,"Compare Archives" plugin is not compatible with idea 2022.1 IC versioin

Answer (score 1):

use  [java decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) and decompile all the .class files and save all files as project structure .

then use meld diff viewer  and compare as folders ..

Answer (score 1):

This application may be what you need, works great and display a simple GUI showing differences. Try [Jarcomp](https://activityworkshop.net/software/jarcomp/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an aparently free tool http://www.extradata.com/products/jarc/

Comment: Thanks. I tried this one. It produces output in XML and further processing is required to make it readable, if you have many classes in .jar

Comment: To me it complained about a missing tools.jar. I do use the JDK, so that's not the problem. I think it doesn't support java7.

Comment: @Tom the link is broken, this answer could be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try http://www.osjava.org/jardiff/ - tool is old and the dependency list is large. From the docs, it looks like worth trying.