# comparing the method signatures changed in two different jars source code

Tags: java, jar

I am stuck up in an odd situation that is in my project an api was being used named `poi 2.5 jar` and now in my project I have upgraded to `poi 3.10 jar`. Now due to this many functionalities have been affected as there are method signatures that have been changed. Please advise how can i find which methods have been changed in these two versions.

Shall I download the source code of these two jars and compare them in beyond compare in then find out the changed method signatures and then where those changed method signatures have been used.

Comment: read the release notes for all versions between 2.5 and 3.10 (haha)

Comment: shouldn't the compiler tell you where you've used changed APIs? These will simply not compile.

Comment: Read this: [comparing-two-jar-files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868803/comparing-two-jar-files)

Comment: Upgrading to a different major version introduces these problems