# Are there some tools for zip files merging?

Tags: jar, merge, zip, diff, merging-data

Are there some tools for zip files merging?

I have a some versions of the same jar file and I would like to do comparison/merging between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed this [Comparing two .jar files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868803/comparing-two-jar-files) already have some great options. (thanks for the great answer @aponomarenko)

For this kind of work, I usually unpack them and use Meld (Linux) and  WinMerge.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Araxis Merge` this supports `*.zip`.